# Duplicate rows before applying pivots in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a big data set that needs to be pivoted to become useful for other applications. It looks like:

```
Time    Name           Value
12:00   Expression     1
13:00   Variable1      1.00E+000
14:00   Volume         8.000
15:00   Expression     2
15:00   Volume         16.000
etc
```

I am using:

```
df_cv=df_cv.pivot_table(index='Time', columns='Name', values='Value').fillna("")
```

I should be pivoted to be:

```
Time    Expression    Variable1   Volume
12:00   1
13:00                 1.00E+000
14:00                             8.000
15:00   2
15:00                             16.000
```

However I now have duplicate values in my time column by which I want to pivot by (One of our machines is now doubling up on time stamps).

A fix is to pivot by the index, but I will lose the Time column.

Alternate fix is to iterate over these values and have some logical statements, but been there - code takes orders of magnitudes longer to run.

*Most of the best fixes require my code to already be in the pivoted form!*

What is the best way to achieve the same output and still have the same formatting?

Comment: When I pivot using your sample data, where `Time` is the index, `15:00` is on the same row and does not create duplicate rows. What is your end-goal desired result?

Comment: I don't get duplicate rows